# Flink job dynamic input parameters

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

One parameter for my flink job is dynamic and i have an api so as to fetch the dynamic value. Can i call the api in source everytime so as to fetch data based on the parameter? Is it the correct way? Will it cause any trouble in flink job?

Comment: What kind of parameter is that ? Where is it used

Comment: Parameter is like a string value from DB which i need to append in url so as to get data. The value keep on changing.

Answer (score 0):

So, If I understand correctly the idea is that You first get some key from dynamoDB and then use that to query external service from the source.

I think that should be possible in general, but there are few things to have in mind when doing that.

1. Not sure about performance of such solution. Are You going to query database constantly? Or somehow just get changes ? There are several things to consider here to have good performance of the source.
2. It may be hard to provide any strong guarantees for such setup, but that depends on the charcteristics of the setup itself. I.e. how are You going to handle failures? How often will key in database change? Will the data be accessible via URL after the key in DB changes ? You probably can keep the last read key in state, so that when the job fails and key in DB changes You can try to read the data for the previous key (for which the job has failed) but that depends on the questions above.

Finally, depending on the characteristics of the setup, it may be possible to use existing Flink operators to achieve that. For example, You can technically stream changes from Database (using one of existing connectors depending on DB) and then use that data in AsyncIO to query external URL, so that finally You have a stream of data from URL witout creating Your own source.